# VS2019+Qt5: UI not updating

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I am using Qt 5.14 in Visual Studio 2019 with the Qt VS tools.
Lately (I am not completely sure when this happened, however I didn't run any updates) the UI does not update after changes in the .ui file.

I am totally aware, that the x.ui files need to be translated into corresponding ui_x.h file, but that does happen, i.e., the changes I make in the .ui files are present in the ui_*.h files after compiling but the changes do not have any effect on the UI that is actually presented during debugging.

Does anyone know how to deal with this or observed similar behaviour?

Comment: Do you use shadow build? Did you make any changes in project file regarding build directory? Check if there are more than one `ui_*.h`  file in project tree for the same `ui` form. Try to run clean and remove all stray `ui_*.h` files.

Comment: No, I don't use shadow build.
No, I did not make any changes to the projeckt file.

I tried both running clean and also deleting all generated files by hand, but neither helps.

No, there are not multiple ui_\*.h files. However, from my understanding, the problem is not in the generation of the ui_\*.h files. Also I noticed, that the elements I added in the \*.ui are present in the moc_\* files also, however they do not show up in the GUI during debugging.